# How to know if an event was updated on fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) and I already made the script to save the event when it is dropped into the calendar or when its re-sized. When the event is set to one day, at certain hour, or is moved from its initial day, the drop function isn't firing.

Is there is a event handler or a callback that works that way?

This is how I render the calendar the first time around

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    buttonText: {
      today: 'today',
      month: 'month',
      week: 'week',
      day: 'day'
    },
    //Random default events
    events: response.data,
    editable: true,
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
    drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped
      var x = Math.random()+1000;
      var y = Math.random()+1000;
      // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
      var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

      // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
      var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

      // assign it the date that was reported
      copiedEventObject.start = date;
      copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
      copiedEventObject.backgroundColor = $(this).css("background-color");
      copiedEventObject.borderColor = $(this).css("border-color");
      copiedEventObject.name = 'event-'+copiedEventObject.id+'-'+x+y;
      saveEvent(copiedEventObject);
    },
    eventResize: function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
      updateEvent(event);
    },
    viewRender: function(view, element){
      var currentdate = view.intervalStart;
      console.log(view);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need to see [drop](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/drop/) and [receive](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/eventReceive/), maybe you need to check the second parameter since you got the wrong time